# How to open a default dialog for window if ShellExecute fails due to no file association in C++?

Tags: winapi, shellexecute, fileopendialog

I can use the windows ShellExecute function to open a file with no problems so long as the file has a correct association.

If no association exists i would like to use the default windows dialog to open the file:

[image]

Is this possible? If so how?

Comment: Use ShellExecuteEx, "open" verb.  Works on Win7, cannot vouch for earlier editions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969321.aspx#canonical) [way](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/11/26/270710.aspx) to show that dialog is to use the openas verb.

```
CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED|COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);
SHELLEXECUTEINFO sei = { sizeof(sei) };
sei.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOASYNC;
sei.nShow = SW_SHOWNORMAL;
sei.lpVerb = "openas";
sei.lpFile = "C:\\yourfile.ext";
ShellExecuteEx(&sei);
```

If you check under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Unknown\shell\openas` you see that this is the same as calling the (undocumented) OpenAs_RunDLL export in shell32.

Comment: Thanks that seemed to work. It is interesting to note, however, that the "openas" verb is not listed under the reference documentation for any of the ShellExecute functions.

Comment: @Darius: the document at the first link mentions the "openas" verb, though admittedly only in passing.

Comment: I use ShellExecute(Handle, 'openas', PChar(txtFile.Text), nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL) in Delphi but get error. It seems 'openas' is not documented, see this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutea

Comment: @alancc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//bb776820(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#canonical-verbs

Answer (score 1):

Execute `RUNDLL32 Shell32,OpenAs_RunDLL path/to/file/to/open`

Comment: Note that `OpenAs_RunDLL` is undocumented and [does not always work.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23566667/rundll32-shell32-dll)

Answer (score 0):

Simply do not use explicit verb. Using a specific verb like 'open' is a big mistake:

- 'open' may be not a default verb (for example, it may be 'play', 'edit' or 'run')
- 'open' may not exists

It is a way more correct to **simply pass NULL as verb**. The system will automatically select most appropriate verb:

- Default verb will be used, if it is set
- 'open' verb will be used, if no default verb is set
- first verb will be used, if no default and 'open' verbs are available
- **if no verbs are assigned - the system will bring "Open with" dialog**

In other words, simple

```
ShellExecute(0, NULL, 'C:\MyFile.StrangeExt', ...);
```

will show "Open with" dialog.

Only use a **specific** verb if you want a **specific** action. E.g. 'print', 'explore', 'runas'. Otherwise - just pass nil.

Comment: I use ShellExecute(Handle, nil, PChar(txtFile.Text), nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL) in Delphi, but still get error. It seems that passing nil will not work if a file has no associated program. It will not invoke the "Open with" dialog